# How to override the function wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data in wc-template-functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Inside my cart I print the variation size (eg. size: 42 ) and I want to change to output by adding an additional size attribute (eg. size: 42 - US7 ) --> I wrote a function based on a custom post type field, that adds the size attribute.

I discovered that woocommerce uses this function to render the cart output:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data.html#3491-3563

```
function wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $flat = false ) {
```

And calls the template file to render the output:

```
wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-item-data.php', array( 'item_data' => $item_data ) );
```

I can't just edit cart-item-data.php file because I need the ID fo the product from the variable $cart_item.

So I thought about overriding the function wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data and pass an additional argument to the template file. But I can't get it to work.

How can a remove_action look in this case?

Something like:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data' );
```

Best, Marko

Answer (score 0):

You can manipualte the 'woocommerce_get_item_data' filter hook in your themes functions.php.

```
// define the woocommerce_get_item_data callback 
function filter_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $item_data; 
}; 
     
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

Source: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_item_data

Works fine for me